# Is there a way to List mvn-deploy to publish artifact repositories?

Tags: java, maven

I was wondering is there a nice way to list all the repositories Maven-Goal maven-deploy will publish artifacts from command-line?

PS. I have checked mvn deploy:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=. Checked the documentation of [mvn-deploy](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) as well.

**env details**

```
Maven : C:\java_tools\maven\apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 1.8.0_241, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows server 2019", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: This is in the distributionManagement tag. You can probably evaluate that and print it to command line.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Thank you for commenting. I understand that this information can be found from distributionManagmentTag my question was more specific on if their is a command which would not need us to check pom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

`mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.distributionManagement.repository.url`